# Can't get the name and age of each student. Instead I get weird characters and age = 0?

Tags: arrays, c, input, struct, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student {
    char name[50];
    int age;
} student;


int main() {
    char name[50];
    int age;

    // Requirement values
    char stop[] = "stop";
    int check = 1;

    int countOfStudents = 0;

    // Array with students
    student* students = malloc(countOfStudents);

    while(check) {

        scanf("%s", &name);

        if(!strcmp(name, stop) == 0) {

            scanf(" %i", &age);
            struct Student student = {*name, age};

            strcpy(students[countOfStudents].name, student.name);
            students[countOfStudents].age = student.age;

            countOfStudents++;
        } else {
            printf("You wrote stop \n");
            check = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfStudents; ++i) {
        printf("Name = %s , Age = %i", students[i].name, students[i].age);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have an array with students. Each student is a struct, and has a name & age.
I have to register each student until the user write "stop".

Input:

```
test
12
stop
```

The output is like this:

```
You wrote stop
ogram Files (x86)
Name = t♀ , Age = 0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder what [these errors](https://godbolt.org/z/cEGbjr4f8) mean.

Comment: Also relevant: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SuperStormer I edited the code now, and there are no warnings. I still don't get the correct output? :O

Comment: `student* students = malloc(countOfStudents);`.  Try a `printf("countOfStudents: %d\n", countOfStudents);` before this line. :) . + some others.

Comment: SuleymanSelcuk  `char name[50]; scanf("%s", name);` --> `scanf("%s", &name);` was an incorrect improvement.  `name` is correct.

Comment: I just tried that, and the age is correct. Although only the first letter of the name is output :O

Comment: SuleymanSelcuk, What do you think `struct Student student = {{*name, age}};` does?  Note `*name` is one `char`.

Comment: ``` warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             struct Student student = {name, age}; ``` I am getting this error if I change it to struct Student student = {name, age}; I am new to C so I am a bit lost actually.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

memory allocation is wrong.
the following code will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
} student;

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    int age;

    char stop[] = "stop";
    int check = 1;

    int countOfStudents = 0;

    student* students = NULL;

    while(check)
    {
        scanf("%49s", name); // 49 + '\0' = 50
        if(!strcmp(name, stop) == 0)
        {
            scanf(" %i", &age);
            if(!students)
            {
                students = (student*) malloc(sizeof(student*)); // allocating for the first
            }
            else
            {
                students = (student*) realloc(students, sizeof(student*)); // allocating 
            }
            strcpy(students[countOfStudents].name, name);
            students[countOfStudents].age = age;
            countOfStudents++;
         }
         else
         {
            printf("You wrote stop \n");
            check = 0;
         }
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfStudents; ++i) 
    {
        printf("Name = %s , Age = %i", students[i].name, students[i].age);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(students);
    students = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(student*)` is the size of a _pointer_.  Suggest `sizeof *students`.

Comment: `realloc(students, sizeof(student*))` --> Need to scale by `countOfStudents+1`.

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem

**Wrong allocation**

```
int countOfStudents = 0;
student* students = malloc(countOfStudents);
```

Allocates zero mmmeory.

Try

```
int countOfStudents = 0;
int Students_MAX = 100;
student* students = malloc(sizeof *students * Students_MAX);
```

and limit iterations:

```
while(countOfStudents < Students_MAX && check)
```

---

Better to use a width limit

```
char name[50];
...
// scanf("%s", name);
scanf("%49s", name);
```

---

`struct Student student = {{*name, age}};` is not the needed initialization.